# ImageMagick on MediaWiki: Thumbnails not being generated : Error Code -1

Tags: imagemagick, mediawiki, thumbnails

Images are uploading but no Thumbnails are being generated.
thumb.php?f="image.png"&width=240 gives
Error generating thumbnail
Error creating thumbnail: Error code: -1

During install of Wikimedia no thumb subdirectory has been created in images. Where is the path of the thumbnails?

The Original file ‎(672 × 671 pixels, file size: 32 KB, MIME type: image/png) should not have a memory problem.

I am stuck trying to find a solution to create those thumbnails.

Is there a page where you can find the error codes?

Comment: Is ImageMagick installed?

Answer (score 2):

- Check that `$wgUploadDirectory` is writeable by PHP.
- Check that `$wgUploadDirectory/thumb` (this is the thumbnail directory) and `$wgUploadDirectory/tmp` exist.
- Check that `$wgImageMagickConvertCommand` is set, exists and is executable (`locate imagemagick` may help).
- Check nginx/Apache/PHP logs for more detailed error.

Failing that, enable *MediaWiki* [debug log](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug).

Further reading: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Common_errors_and_symptoms#Image_Thumbnails_not_working_and/or_appearing.

Comment: Thank you Alexander for your guidance.

The Upload directory should be writeable because previous images (no thumbs) are in this directory in different subdirectories with numbers.
Both $wgUploadDirectory/thumb and $wgUploadDirectory/temp were not defined in LocalSettings although the directories exist. Temp was created during installation of the Wiki but thumb was not created.

I tried the debug log advice, but no errors were reported, only this http://www.creafree.org/cb/Error%20%20Wiki.JPG happens.

[[File:CreaWiki_small.png|20px|test]]  generates the error

Comment: Did you create `$wgUploadDirectory/temp` directory manually?

Comment: No, only the thumb directory was not on the server. The temp directory is a subdirectory in images and created during setup

Comment: Then create it in `images`.

Comment: I'm really stuck with this Error code: -1. If only I would know what this Error means....

This is my localsettings: $wgUploadPath = "$wgScriptPath/images"; 
$wgUploadDirectory = "$IP/images";
$wgThumbnailEpoch = 20210408133818;
$wgEnableUploads = true;
$wgUseImageResize = true;
$wgUseImageMagick = true;
$wgImageMagickConvertCommand = "/usr/bin/convert";
$wgGenerateThumbnailOnParse = true;